# Where is the result of word embedding after running word2vec.py in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

I have run the 'word2vec.py' file under the folder of '/tensorflow/models/embedding/'. But I can't find the result of word embedding in the output folder, and there are only model files and some unknown files like this:

[result files of word2vec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbT2m.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since, from the paper of Mikolov, it is clear that the ouput of word embeddings of all the words are not obtained in the final layer. Rather they chop off the final layer and take the weights of the hidden layer which is of the dimension: [vocab_size x embd_dim], i.e. Each row is a word vector (dimension: embd_dim) of the corresponding word.

Refer this for better understanding: http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/

So, in the tensorflow implementation, the `tf.embedding_lookup` has the word embeddings of all the words. 
It's mentioned in **line 26** of the file `word2vec.py` in `/tensorflow/models/embedding/`

```
24 The key ops used are:
25 * placeholder for feeding in tensors for each example.
26 * embedding_lookup for fetching rows from the embedding matrix.
27 * sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits to calculate the loss.
28 * GradientDescentOptimizer for optimizing the loss.
29 * skipgram custom op that does input processing.
```